# gridview bottom menu

Tags: android, gridview, android-bottom-nav-view

Increasingly I notice in applications this kind of menu. **Who has ideas how to implement it?**

[image]

Comment: checkout https://inducesmile.com/android/android-tab-with-swipe-views-viewpager-fragmentpageradapter-in-android-studio/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this xml for the grid view ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```